# How do I encode a file name for download?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, encoding

When the file name is "Algunas MARCAS que nos acompañan" ASP.NET MVC raise an `System.FormatException` when I try to download that file. But if the file name is "Asistente de Gerencia Comercial" it doesn't.

I guess this is because something related to `UTF-8` encoding, but I don't know how to encode that string.

If I'm right, how can I encode the string in `UTF-8` encoding? If I'm not right, what is my problem?

Comment: How are you sending the file back to the user now? Using `System.Web.Mvc.FileResult`? Can you post your code?

Comment: The weird thing is that `System.Web.Mvc.FileResult` internally uses `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition` to generate the header that it adds to the response. I would have expected that class to be able to handle whatever string encoding is necessary to make this work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I encode file name like this for downloading,

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= " + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
```

Comment: This replaces spaces with +, which may not be what you want.

Comment: **NOTE**: For the correct solution in modern times, see RFC6266: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6266

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode causes replacing spaces with plus signs, HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode is solution for plus sign problem.

Answer (score 6):

Based on ZZ Coder answer, and because I'm using FileResult, I decided to encode the file name as:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

Answer (score 2):

We had an issue where Chrome was changing filenames that contained underscores to the name of the page the file was being downloaded from.

Using `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(filename)` as suggested by Furkan Ekinci in the comments fixed it for us.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been known for years. As far as I can tell, there currently is no interoperable way to do this, so the answer is to only support one set of browsers, or to do User Agent sniffing.

Test cases and links at: http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/

Answer (score 1):

The only trick that works (in all browsers) for me is:

```
Dim headerFileName As String = IIf(Request.Browser.Browser = "InternetExplorer" Or Request.UserAgent.Contains("Edge"), Uri.EscapeDataString(file.Name), file.Name)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=""" + headerFileName + """")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently fought with this a bit, having many potential languages being used for the file names (Chinese is good to test with).  Here is something close to what I ended up with (other implementation details excluded):

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("é", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also: HttpUtility considered harmful:
http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2008/03/httputilityurlencode-considered-harmful.html

I'm just going to punt and replace " " with "_" and call it a day =)

Answer (score 0):

note that using UTF encoding **replaces** the spaces in the file name into '+', using either the following codes produce the same results:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("é", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using **httpUtility** that replaces the spaces in the file name with "+" using the following code resolve the problem:

```
string attachment = String.Format("attachment; filename={0}",Server.UrlPathEncode(file.Name.TrimEnd()));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", attachment);
```

please note that if you retrieve file name from data set you may need trim the name first! 
you have to also add the following lines of code in advance:

```
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.HeaderEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
Response.ContentEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
```