# Internet explorer does not download file with Unicode name through Jquery FileDownload

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, unicode, encoding

I am trying to download a file, retrieved from a server by using on the client side the fileDownload from jquery. The MVC controller returns a simple object of type **FileDownloadResult** :

```
public sealed class FileDownloadResult : IHttpActionResult, IDisposable
{
        private readonly MemoryStream _dataStream;
        private readonly string _fileName;

        ... various methods() ...
}
```

The file I want to download is named: FRISS_db_DiagramЁФ.
On google chrome it works fine and the file is downloaded with the correct filename even in case it's in unicode.
On internet explorer instead the Content-disposition header shows as filename:

=?utf-8?B?RlJJU1NfZGJfRGlhZ3JhbdCB0KQucG5n?="

And therefore the file is downloaded with this corrupted name. How can I make sure that the right encoding is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here ([How do I encode a file name for download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598373/how-do-i-encode-a-file-name-for-download))

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename= " + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
```